# PHP - Why its not printing the variable although it prints text?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, printing

I had some problem with this php cause it was not returning anything from the DB, so I realised that maybe it was not receiving the variable from the $_POST. So I tried to print it and it didnt return nothing. So ive entered its value manually, but it stills printing nothing! Although it prints texts, if there was a syntax problem in the script it wouldn't print the texts too (i think). So I don't know what is wrong.

The HTML part with the tables get printed!
At the end there is a "echo "anything";" and it is also printed! The only thing that is not printed is the $nome variable.

Sorry for the portuguese texts, but you don't need to worry about them.

```
    <?php

        //$nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $nome = "renato";  //ive set the value manually for tests

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=myserver;dbname=mydb', 'myuser', 'mypw');


        if ($nome = ""){
            $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
        }
        else{
            $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nome='".$nome."'");
        }

        echo $nome; //prints nothing!
    ?>

    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>ID</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>NOME</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>ENDERECO</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>BAIRRO</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>CIDADE</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>FIS_JUR</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>RG</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>CPF</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>TEL</h3>
            </td><td>
                <h3>TEL2</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>DATA_NASC</h3>
            </td>       
        </tr>


//this table gets printed!


    <?php

        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td> {$row['id']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['nome']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['endereco']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['bairro']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['cidade']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['fis_jur']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['rg']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['cpf']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['tel']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['tel2']}
            </td>

            <td> {$row['data_nasc']}
            </td>
        </tr>";

//this one prints nothing!
        }

        echo $nome; //prints nothing
        echo "anything"; //yes, this one gets printed
        $pdo = null;
        $sql = null;
    ?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
if ($nome = ""){
```

with

```
if ($nome == ""){
```

you are assigning the value instead of comparing.

Answer (score 0):

```
`the problem is that single = sign. rather use double == for comparing.`

the batter way checking empty string use

` if ( empty($nome) ){
    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
}else{
    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nome='".$nome."'");
}
```